# ignore consecutive dates with same code

Tags: excel, formula

.  I keep a spreadsheet which shows the employee name, the date, then the occurence ("A" for absent, "L" for late, etc...  I need a formula that will ignore consecutive absences - as they are counted as one.  (And because we are closed on Sundays - absences occuring on Saturday through Monday would be considered consecutive.)

Comment: Can you post any existing code that you have so that we can look at what you already have and try to help you from there? It would make sense that you could just sort by day # (convert it to 1-365)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Assuming you have your data in column A type this formula in column B:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2="A", A3="A"), AND(A2="A", A1="A")), "", IF(A2="A", 1, ""))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: here is a sample of the data. I need a formula that will not count consecutive "A"s - on consecutive dates...                           Name Date Code
Agent 1 20-Apr A
Agent 1 21-Apr A
Agent 1 22-Apr A

Comment: I'm having understanding your comment. Did you try the formula I've given?